# Can't get data by joining 3 tables in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to get data from 3 tables using `join` in laravel, but it's not working.

**code**:

```
Blog::join('category_blogs', 'category_blogs.id', '=', 'blogs.category_id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'blogs.user_id')
        ->where('category_blogs.id', $search_by_cat)
        ->where('blogs.title', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')
        
        ->paginate(30,array('blogs.*', 'category_blogs.category_name','users.user_first_name'));
```

Comment: which one you expecting ?inner join or left join

Comment: I am actually not good at join, I just want to get all info from "blogs", some info from "category_blogs", some info from "users"

Comment: then change join to leftjoin

Comment: for both tables ?

Comment: yes try once to check

Comment: ok , still not working

Comment: difficult assume whats the isuse.better remove where condtion line by line then joins.its easy to debug .we cant predict without errror

Comment: It's working now lol - thanks for the help :)

Comment: @azim.great .good luck

Answer (score 0):

You try and use with() as well. Just define the models you want inside it and add the relationship in the Model file. And when you use with() it will get you all the columns from those tables.